# find the volume of the solid enclosed by this equation. How to visualize it?

Tags: calculus, integration

How do we find the volume of the solid 
$$ ( \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} +\frac{z^2}{c^2})^2 = \frac{x}{h} $$ ?
I tried to use Wolframalpha to plot it but it doesn't give me the plot.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the equation as

$$\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=\sqrt{\frac xh}-\frac{x^2}{a^2}.$$

This represents an ellipse in the vertical plane at $x$, with an *area* proportional to the RHS. The latter expression is positive from $x=0$ until $x^3=a^4/h$.

The volume is an egg of Colombus* with elliptic cross-sections. Its measure will be $\pi bc$ times the integral of the RHS.

$$V=\pi\frac{a^2}{3h}bc.$$

(*With a pretty flat base.)

Answer (score 1):

For first, let we set $x = a u,y=b v, z=c w,\delta=\frac{a}{h}$.

It is sufficient to find the volume of the solid enclosed by:
$$ (u^2+v^2+w^2)^2 = \delta u.\tag{1}$$
If $(1)$ is fullfilled, then $u\geq 0$, and we can compute the volume by slicing the solid according the the value of $u$. The section is a circle having square radius:
$$ R_u^2 = \sqrt{\delta u} - u^2 $$
so, by Cavalieri's principle, the volume is given by:
$$ \int_{0}^{\delta^{1/3}}\pi(\sqrt{\delta u}-u^2)\,du = \frac{\pi \delta}{3}\tag{2} $$
and the volume of the original solid is just:
$$ V = abc\cdot\frac{\pi\delta}{3} = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{3h}a^2bc}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: You forgot that the LHS is squared.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: you're right, now fixed.

Comment: Could you explain more about how you sue Cavalieri's principle to get equation (2)?  Are you using shell method (to compute volume of revolution?   Also, what volume do you refer in (2) and why is in (3), you multiply that by $abc$?

Comment: @Paul555: I apply the Cavalieri's method by computing the area of the section $u=\text{something}$. The volume I consider in $(2)$ is the volume of the solid given by equation $(1)$. The scaling factor comes from the Jacobian of the map $(x,y,z)=(au,bv,cw)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Solid 'enclosed' by
$\ds{\pars{{x^{2} \over a^{2}} + {y^{2} \over b^{2}} + {z^{2} \over c^{2}}}^{2}
     ={x \over h}:\ {\large ?}}$.

---

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\left.\int_{{\mathbb R}^{3}}\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z\,
\right\vert_{\pars{%
{x^{2} \over a^{2}} + {y^{2} \over b^{2}} + {z^{2} \over c^{2}}}^{2}\
<\ {x \over h}}}
=\left.\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z\,
\right\vert_{\pars{%
{x^{2} \over a^{2}} + {y^{2} \over b^{2}} + {z^{2} \over c^{2}}}^{2}\
<\ {x \over \verts{h}}}
\\[5mm]&=\left.\verts{abc}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}
r^{2}\sin\pars{\theta}\,\dd r\,\dd\theta\,\dd\phi\,
\right\vert_{r^{4}\ <\ \verts{a \over h}r\sin\pars{\theta}\cos\pars{\phi}}
\\[5mm]&=\left. 2\verts{abc}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}
r^{2}\sin\pars{\theta}\,\dd r\,\dd\theta\,\dd\phi\,
\right\vert_{r^{3}\ <\ -\verts{a \over h}\sin\pars{\theta}\cos\pars{\phi}}
\\[5mm]&=\left. 2\verts{abc}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}
r^{2}\sin\pars{\theta}\,\dd r\,\dd\theta\,\dd\phi\,
\right\vert_{r^{3}\ <\ \verts{a \over h}\sin\pars{\theta}\sin\pars{\phi}}
\\[5mm]&=2\verts{abc}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi}
\int_{0}^{%
\braces{\verts{a}\sin\pars{\theta}\sin\pars{\phi}/\verts{h}}^{\,\,\,\,\,1/3}}
r^{2}\sin\pars{\theta}\,\dd r\,\dd\theta\,\dd\phi
\\[5mm]&=2\verts{abc}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\pi}
{\verts{a}\sin\pars{\theta}\sin\pars{\phi}/\verts{h} \over 3}
\sin\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta\,\dd\phi
\\[5mm]&={2 \over 3}\,a^{2}\verts{bc \over h}\ \overbrace{%
\bracks{\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{2}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta}}
^{\ds{=\ \dsc{\pi \over 2}}}\ \overbrace{%
\bracks{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin\pars{\phi}\,\dd\phi}}^{\ds{=\ \dsc{1}}}\ =\
\color{#66f}{\large{1 \over 3}\,\pi a^{2}\verts{bc \over h}}
\end{align}

Comment: Already correctly answered twice.

Comment: Hi Felix, I found your method easy to follow but one thing I don't understand is how you get a factor of 2 in line3 and how you change the upper limit of integration for $\phi$. Could you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

I used this for visualization with WolframAlpha:

[image]
[image]

Example with $a = b = c = h = 1$.